# Could not connect to cassandra with cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, connection

I want to connect to cassandra but got this error:

```
$ bin/cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'192.168.1.200': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('192.168.1.200', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cassandra cqlsh - connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121904/cassandra-cqlsh-connection-refused)

Comment: i read it but them not working for me.

Comment: @Hadi if you'r still interested in this, I found a solution that worked for me. Had the exact same error message.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple.

The machine is **actively refusing it** because your system does not have cassandra running on it. Follow the following steps to completely get rid of this trouble :

1. Install **Cassandra** from DataStax (Datastax-DDC; Cassandra version 3).
2. Go to `~\installation\path\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin`.
3. Open up `cmd` there. (Use `Alt`+`F`+`P` to open it if you are on windows 8 or later).
4. type `cassandra -f` this will generate a lot of stuff on the window and you must get the last line as `INFO  11:32:31 Created default superuser role 'cassandra'`
5. Now open another `cmd` window in the same folder.
6. Type `cqlsh`

This should give you a prompt, without any error.

I also discovered that **this error doesn't pop up if I use cassadra v2.x** found here [Archived version of Cassandra](http://www.planetcassandra.org/archived-versions-of-datastaxs-distribution-of-apache-cassandra/). *I don't know why :( (If you find out please comment).*

So, if the above steps do not work, you can always go back to Cassandra v2.x.

Cheers.

Comment: You are briliiant , u saved a lot of time , wasted almost a day :)

Comment: @MeganFox always there to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have started Cassandra server, then provide the `host` and `port` as the arguments.

```
$ bin/cqlsh 127.0.0.1 4092
```

Comment: no it got error , should i install thrift for cassandra??

Comment: @Hadi you don't need to install Thrift since CQL is not using Thrift. Can you be more clear of what error?

Comment: this is my error   :     $ cqlsh
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})

Comment: this video for install cassandra installed thrift   :      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNxgviqDLCs

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem. This worked for me.

Go to any directory for example E:\ (doesn't have to be the same disc as the cassandra installation)

Create the following directories

```
E:\cassandra\storage\commitlogs
E:\cassandra\storage\data
E:\cassandra\storage\savedcaches
```

Then go to your cassandra installations `conf` path. In my case.

```
D:\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\conf
```

Open cassandra.yaml. Edit the lines containing: `data_file_directories, commitlog_directory, saved_caches_directory` to look like the code below (change paths accordingly to where you created the folders)

```
data_file_directories:
    - E:\cassandra\storage\data

commitlog_directory: E:\cassandra\storage\commitlog

saved_caches_directory: E:\cassandra\storage\savedcaches
```

Then open the cmd (I did it as administrator, but didn't check if it is necessary) to your cassandra installations `bin` path. In my case.

```
D:\DataStax-DDC\apache-cassandra\bin
```

run `cassandra -f`

Lots of stuff will be logged to your screen.
You should now be able to run `cqlsh` and all other stuff without problems.

Edit: The operating system was windows10 64bit

Edit2: If it stops working after a while check if the service is till running using `nodetool status`. If it isn't follow [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra_win/3.0/cassandra/initialize/referenceStartStopWin.html) instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem on a Win32 windows 7 machine.

1. Check if you have JAVA installed correctly and JAVA_HOME variable set.
2. Once you have checked the java installation and set JAVA_HOME, uninstall Cassandra and install it again.

Hopefully this would solve the problem. Mine was solved after applying the above two steps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mention *host*, *user*, *password* for cassandra cqlsh connection. Default cassandra cqlsh *user* is **cassandra** and *password* is **cassandra**.

```
$ bin/cqlsh <host> -u cassandra -p cassandra
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had same problem. I applied many methods given on google and youtube but none of them worked in my case. Finally, I applied the following 3 steps and it worked in my case:-

1. Create a folder without any space in C or D whichever is your system drive. eg:- C:\cassandra
2. Install Cassandra in this folder instead of installing in"Program Files".
   After installation, it will be like this- C:\cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.6
3. Copy python 2.7 installed in bin folder i.e.,C:\cassandra\apache-cassandra-3.11.6\bin

Now your program is ready for work.

Answer (score 0):

There is no special method to connect cqlsh it simple as below:-

$ bin/cqlsh 127.0.0.1(host IP) 9042 or $ bin/cqlsh 127.0.0.1(host IP) 9160 (if older version of Cassandra)

Don't forget to check port connectivity if you are connecting cqlsh to remote host. Also you can use username/password if you enabled by default it is disabled.