# Connection with Cassandra servers locally

Tags: cassandra

C:\Users\spant2\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\bin>cassandra -f

Starting Cassandra Server

C:\Users\spant2\Downloads\apache-cassandra-3.11.5\bin>cqlsh

Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(10061, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")})

Comment: Please show us some of your code and have a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: please edit your question and add the command that you are using to connect to Cassandra

Comment: @abi_pat I updated the commands. Can you please suggest?

Comment: is your cassandra node running on same host?

Comment: based on your question, I am assuming your cassandra node is running on same machine/host. Refer https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html and mention host port parameters. If you still face the issue, I think you may need to update your hosts file - https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: if the problem still persists, follow this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/36846543/3601406

Comment: Try starting cassandra with `cassandra -p cassandra.pid` instead.

Answer (score 1):

can you check if any other process/application  is running on port 9042

linux command

```
netstat -anp|grep -i 9042
```

if any process is already running on same port, kill that process.

Answer (score 0):

Please use cqlsh with IP address if you set rpc_address is public IP.

You may refer below 
https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html

Also, please check whether port 9042 is open or not on your system.