# cqlsh connection error: 'ref() does not take keyword arguments'

Tags: python, linux, cassandra, cqlsh

I've tried all the measures from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121904/cassandra-cqlsh-connection-refused) and [Cassandra doc](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/GettingStarted).

I've tried running all the versions of Cassandra including the latest release 3.7 from tarball and Debian package, but I keep getting errors when I execute `cqlsh`.

Error:

> Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})

I had no problem running Cassandra before I upgraded my Linux Mint from 17.3 to 18.

I believe I installed all the necessary packages such as java 8 and python 2.7.12.

I think the problem exists in cassandra.yaml file since the default setting isn't working, but I'm not sure how to configure properly to get it running.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are running into [CASSANDRA-11850](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850), where cqlsh breaks with Python 2.7.11+.  This ticket has been marked as "Resolved" and a patch has been applied to Cassandra 3.9 which has not been released yet.

> I believe I installed all the necessary packages such as java 8 and python 2.7.12.

In the interim (until 3.9 is released) you can roll back to Python 2.7.10, and cqlsh should work (not trivial).  Otherwise, [DataStax DevCenter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/devcenter/doc/devcenter/dcInstallation.html) should work with Cassandra 3.7.

**Edit 20161020**

Cassandra 3.9 was released a few weeks ago, and can now be [downloaded](http://cassandra.apache.org/download/).

Comment: I rolled back to Python 2.7.10, and now it's working. Thank you.

Comment: Really helped. downgraded 2.7.10 and its started working

Answer (score 24):

refer https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850

After setting environment variable

```
CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=TRUE
```

it resolved.

I use windows 7, python 2.7.12, cassandra 3.7

Comment: I used `export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=TRUE` before running connect command as I don't have access to set the environment variable... thanks..

Comment: This does not work for me on Mac. But `PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/bin/:$PATH cqlsh` helps

Comment: `export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=TRUE` worked for me in Ubuntu18.04 and java8 and python2.7.17 .

Answer (score 10):

Need to add following command

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install cassandra-driver
export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
```

Comment: Worked for 2.1.0

Answer (score 3):

This works for Ubuntu 16.04 in Amazon EC2:

```
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install python-cassandra python3-cassandra
CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=TRUE cqlsh "$(ec2metadata --local-ipv4)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Even if after rolling back to python 2.7.10, the issue persists. It means the python 2.7.10 is not set as the default python version.

Go to /usr/bin directory and check the different python versions available, say python2.7 corresponds to version 2.7.10 ( you can check it by running command python2.7 in your terminal and the python version will be mentioned in the first line of the Interpreter,try the same with all other python versions available in the folder to find the one which corresponds to version 2.7.10).

Now, use the following commands to make correct python version (python2.7 in my case) as default choice

**update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python2.7**

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible as you have not installed cassandra-driver.

As I also faced the same problem and I solved using following such steps.

Try installing python pip then install cassandra-driver.

1.sudo apt install python-pip
2.pip install cassandra-driver