# Apache Cassandra 3.7 CQLSH 'Unable to connect to any servers'

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Apache cassandra version 3.7 is running on Ubuntu server 16.04 fine, all parts of apache cassandra started up no problem, the issue is, i go to connect using cqlsh:
$ CQLSH (My IP Address) 9160 
then it says:
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers',
{'10.0.0.13': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)}
)
i seen there was a bug for it:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850
but its for version cqlsh --version: cqlsh 5.0.1
cassandra -v: 3.5 (also occurs with 3.0.6)

Someone commented on my Apache Cassandra ticket:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-12402
stating:
Use the workaround described in the ticket:
If you have an up-to-date cassandra-driver installed, you can disable the embedded driver by setting the environment variable CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED to any non empty string, for example export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true.

QUESTIONS ARE:

How do i disable the up-to-date cassandra-driver? what directory is it in? what file name? also if i disable it, will i be able to connect using CQLSH? what tool did you guys use to connect to apache cassandra to run commands etc. Besides CQLSH directly on the server?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As described in the ticket - define environment variable CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED and export it.

```
export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
```

It will tell *cqlsh* (which is Python program) to use external Cassandra Python driver, not the one bundled with the distribution. The bundled Cassandra driver is located in */opt/datastax-ddc-3.7.0/bin*, the file name is *cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.0.0-6af642d.zip*

Then run *cqlsh*, which is located in */opt/datastax-ddc-3.7.0/bin*.

```
./cqlsh
```

It is possible that you will need to install Cassandra Python driver (if it was not installed already) using:

```
pip install cassandra-driver
```

Note - folder names are for Datastax Cassandra build.

Comment: Thanks, though had to use "sudo pip install cassandra-driver".  Putting this out there because it timed out before getting the permissions error message.

Comment: I am still getting another error after install the latest cassandra driver: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/cassandra/bin/cqlsh", line 109, in <module>
    from cassandra.cluster import Cluster, PagedResult
ImportError: cannot import name PagedResult

Any ideas?

Comment: @Patrick this message has to do withthe **cassandra-driver** version. 
Try: `pip install cassandra-driver==2.7.2`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably due to python version.
Here is a ticket marked as resolved. [cqlsh connection error: 'ref() does not take keyword arguments'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616858/cqlsh-wont-connect-on-linux)

I tried on my side. After reverting python to 2.7.10, it works well.