# CQLSH ProtocolError

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-3.0

I have an error with cqlsh 
when I type cqlsh to start cassandra shell where cassandra server is already started this error appears

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': ProtocolError("cql_version '3.3.1' is not supported by remote (w/ native protocol). Supported versions: [u'3.4.2']",)})
```

I also already installed cassandra-driver and 
export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
but nothing changes 
could anyone have any idea to solve this ?!!
my cassandra version is 3.6

Answer (score 7):

**The protocol version you are connecting is not supported by the version of your cassandra's protocol**

**Try adding `--cqlversion="3.4.2"` as argument in cqlsh**

```
bin/cqlsh --cqlversion="3.4.2"
```

Comment: when I type your suggestion command this error appears "Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616858/cqlsh-connection-error-ref-does-not-take-keyword-arguments

Comment: helped. Thanks))

Comment: Worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try following commands

```
sudo apt install python-pip
pip install cassandra-driver
export CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=true
```