# Cant' connect to Cassandra with cqlsh

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

When i tried to connect to my cassandra cluster with cqlsh, i had this following error :

`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

So i go to the cassandra.yaml file but my `rpc_adress` and `listen_address` parameters are goods.

There is my `listen_adress` :

`# ipv4. If there is only one address it will be selected regardless of ipv4/ipv6.
listen_address: localhost`

`# listen_interface: eth0`

`# listen_interface_prefer_ipv6: false`

And my `rpc_address` :

`rpc_address: localhost`

`# port for Thrift to listen for clients on
rpc_port: 9160`

I also tried to modify the file, but i dont have the right for it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29121904/cassandra-cqlsh-connection-refused

Comment: I already tried this. It didn't work

Comment: What is the value of `native_transport_port` ?

Comment: and `broadcast_rpc_address` ?

Comment: `native_transport_port` : 9042 and `broadcast_rpc_address` : 1.2.3.4

Comment: Is broadcast_rpc_address commented out ?

Comment: No it is commented like this :  `# broadcast_rpc_address: 1.2.3.4`

Comment: Though `broadcast_rpc_address` is disable, `rpc_address` will used for connection.

Comment: Can you telnet on `localhost 9042`  ??

Comment: No I can't. That have no sense, yesterday was working great.          `Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused`

Comment: Try nodetool status

Comment: Answer of the nodetool status : `nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connexion refusée (Connection refused)'.`

Comment: Are you sure your cassandra is running ?? I think your cassandra is down

Comment: Yes my Cassandra is running. I check the status of the service with this command : `sudo service cassandra status`

Comment: And i got this answer : `Active: active (exited) since mar. 2017-05-09 13:21:27 CEST; 2h 37min ago`

Comment: your cassandra is not running. exited. try `ps -aux | grep cassandra`

Comment: I had this answer : `sevin     3819  0.0  0.0  14264   988 pts/2    S+   09:02   0:00 grep --color=auto cassandra`

Comment: I restart the Cassandra service with `systemctl restart cassandra`. Now it is running but it still didn't work

Comment: paste your system.log

Comment: ERROR [main] 2017-05-10 09:13:30,184 JVMStabilityInspector.java:79 - Exiting due to error while processing commit log during initialization.
org.apache.cassandra.db.commitlog.CommitLogReplayer$CommitLogReplayException: Unexpected error deserializing mutation; saved to /tmp/mutation8492466347162558035dat.  This may be caused by replaying a mutation against a table with the same name but incompatible schema.  Exception follows: java.io.IOError: java.io.EOFException

Comment: Your cassandra is not starting because of this error

Comment: This is the last error. My login attemps are not written in the file, I dont know why

Comment: This append when i restart Cassandra and trying to use cqlsh

Comment: So, what im supposed to do to start my Cassandra ? I search and i didn't found solutions

Comment: Is your commitlog data important ? Commit log saved your unflushed data.  If you don't care about the data, removing files from \data\commitlogs should be easiest solution. Then restart cassandra

Comment: I did it and now it works great ! And my data are still here. Thank you for your help